# .htaccess denied vs out of wwwroot

Tags: linux, security, .htaccess, permissions

I need to upload to my server a high sensitive data file to be used by PHP scripts. Please, tell me what's the most secure way and why:

- Putting it in a folder not under www root
- Putting it under www root but denying access with .htaccess rule

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have ftp/sftp/ssh access to this server, there's no reason not to put it outside of the www document root. If you have a hosting service that only grants you access to the www document root, then you'll have to go with the second solution, but the first is much more secure.

Htaccess can be bypassed if there is a vulnerable script on your site. There are tools that, if placed correctly, files inside the document root and be uploaded by a remote attacker or even replaced. For example, there are [php "remote file managers"](http://packetstormsecurity.org/files/86230/WSH-PHP-Backdoor.html) that allows a remote attacker to change permissions, edit, or replace existing files, including your htaccess file. If you're running a site like Wordpress, or some other CMS, that aren't exactly super secure by themselves, that have a lot of third party plugins, those plugins could be vulnerable to attacks, and if you happen to be using one, your htaccess file's access restrictions could be bypassed.

When the sensitive information is outside of the document root, an attacker who has access to the document root won't be able to access these files and vulnerabilities in your scripts are a lot less likely to affect access to these files. There most likely needs to be a system level exploit to be able to gain access to files outside of the docuement root.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was thinking, but please tell me why one reason because it's much more secure. I need to convince hosting service.

Comment: @user1294101 sure. I expanded my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensing answer. But if attacker gain access to document root, he could include via PHP files out of document root, exactly as I am going to do with my php scripts. Is this right?

Comment: @user1294101 yes, but they won't be able to see what files are there outside of what you are including. They wouldn't be able arbitrarily browse outside of the document root. You could even only include other php files from the document root, then from those php files access the sensitive data. Placing stuff outside of document root isn't a guarantee by any stretch, but it does prevent some things from happening (webserver misconfiguration exposing sensitive data), and make other things harder to do.